# converting mips to c

Tags: mips

So here I have this function in mips. I am trying to convert it to c.

```
1 mystery:  bne $0, $a0, recur  # 
2           li $v0, 0       #
3           jr $ra          #
4 recur:        sub $sp, $sp, 8     #
5           sw $ra, 4($sp)  #
6           sub $a0, $a0, 1     #
7           jal mystery         #
8           sw $v0, 0($sp)  #
9           jal mystery         #
10          lw $t0, 0($sp)  #
11          addu $v0, $v0, $t0  #
12          addu $v0, $v0, 1    #
13          add $a0, $a0, 1     #
14          lw $ra, 4($sp)  #
15          add $sp, $sp, 8     #
16          jr $ra          #
```

I mean just looking at this, it looks recursive

int mystery (int n) {

}

it looks like something starts out at 8, but i get lost very quickly with the jumps to mystery.
it seems the end case is it it's equal to 0

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a convoluted way of calculating `2^n-1`, where `n` is the input to the function.

A C translation might look something like this:

```
int mystery(int n)
{
  if (n != 0) {
    return mystery(n - 1) + mystery(n - 1) + 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```